# Div one inside the other bug

Tags: html, css

```css
#container {
                background-color: darkslategrey;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 700px;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .uno { 
                width: 650px; 
                height: 400px; 
                background-color: black; 
            }
            .due {
                width: 100%;
                height: 300px;
                background-color: #175C80;
                opacity: 0.9;
            }

            .tre {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50%;
                background-color: aliceblue; 
            }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="uno">
        <div class="due">
            <div class="tre"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hi, I have a big problem with Chrome: when I put 4 div, one inside the other, I have a gap of 1px right on second div. I tried all but nothing is solved. In Safari all this there no, why?
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRNS9.png)
[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPn5q.png)

Comment: The container is closed!

Comment: works fine for me in chrome - I see no black of `une`.  Not sure what your above comment is about either

Comment: This problem is only on chrome iMac. i tried on Firefox, Safari, Opera e Chrome for iPhone and this bug there no!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the 50px distance between .uno and #container? If yes, it's because the container is 50px wider than .uno. Decrease the #container's width to 650px or increase the .uno's width to 700px.

```
#container {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.uno {
    width: 650px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
}
...
```

OR

```
#container {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.uno {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
}
...
```

Comment: Also, if you'd like to keep the size and want .uno to get centered, use margin: 0 auto for .uno

Comment: I badly explained myself: the problem is on second div. If u watch Chrome photo u can see a little black line; while in Safari photo this isn't there!

Comment: I see. Though, it works for my well on Chrome but I guess it'll be solved if you add "float: left" to .uno

Comment: Nothing. I resolved with overflow:hidden in .uno and adding 1px at width of tre. But is curious this!